# Altitude Above channel in GRASS 6.4

Tags: grass-gis, r, saga

I'm fairly new to the GIS world and GRASS (come from econometric background), I would like to do some species distribution modeling using R and GRASS.

So I started to read the book of Tomislav Hengl : **A practical guide to geostatistical mapping**, and specially **chapter 8** about species modeling (using the bei dataset in the spatstat R package).

The same analysis is also on the author wiki page : http://spatial-analyst.net/wiki/index.php?title=Species_Distribution_Modelling

Tomislav Hengl, used mainly SAGA-GIS and R, and I would like to do the same analysis using R and GRASS (through spgrass6).

The problem is that i don't know the equivalent of 
SAGA ta_channel module 3 (altitude above channel) in GRASS, so far I tried r.stream.distance to compute elevation above stream but the result are really different.

This is the part of original code i want to do (problem is where there are **):

```
library(gstat)
library(spatstat)
library(splancs)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(adehabitat)
library(rgdal)
library(lattice)
library(RSAGA)
# General settings for plots:
trellis.par.get("fontsize") -> fontsize
fontsize$default<-34
fontsize$points<-22
fontsize$text<-34
# environnement pour SAGA
monenv <- rsaga.env(path = "/usr/bin/", modules = "/usr/lib/saga")
#-------------------------------
# 1. Data import and preparation
#-------------------------------

# Load the data:
data(bei)
str(bei)
str(bei.extra, max.level=1)
plot(bei.extra$elev, main="Beilschmiedia (Tropical rain forest trees)")
plot(bei, add=TRUE, pch=16, cex=0.3)
class(bei.extra[[1]])
# Export to a GIS (for visual exploration):
grids <- as(bei.extra[[1]], "SpatialGridDataFrame")
names(grids)[1] <- "elev"
grids$grad <- as(bei.extra[[2]], "SpatialGridDataFrame")$v
writeGDAL(grids[1], "dem.mpr", "ILWIS")
write.asciigrid(grids["elev"], "dem.asc")
write.asciigrid(grids["grad"], "grad.asc")
bei.pnt <- data.frame(x=bei$x, y=bei$y, no=rep(1, length(bei$x)))
coordinates(bei.pnt) <- ~x+y
writeOGR(bei.pnt, "bei.shp", "bei", "ESRI Shapefile")
# reformat the point pattern so it fits the grids:
bei.ppp <- ppp(coordinates(bei.pnt)[,1], coordinates(bei.pnt)[,2], marks=bei.pnt$no, window=as(grids[1], "owin"))
# Generate the wetness index and vertical distance from the channel network in SAGA and import back to R:
rsaga.esri.to.sgrd(in.grids="dem.asc", out.sgrds="dem.sgrd", in.path=getwd())
rsaga.geoprocessor(lib="ta_hydrology", module=15, param=list(DEM="dem.sgrd", C="catharea.sgrd", GN="catchslope.sgrd", CS="modcatharea.sgrd", SB="twi.sgrd", T=10))
rsaga.geoprocessor(lib="ta_channels", module=0, param=list(ELEVATION="dem.sgrd", CHNLNTWRK="chnlntwrk.sgrd", CHNLROUTE="channel_route.sgrd", SHAPES="channels.shp", INIT_GRID="dem.sgrd", DIV_CELLS=5, MINLEN=10))
**rsaga.geoprocessor(lib="ta_channels", module=3, param=list(ELEVATION="dem.sgrd", CHANNELS="chnlntwrk.sgrd", ALTITUDE="achan.sgrd", THRESHOLD=0.1, NOUNDERGROUND=TRUE))
rsaga.sgrd.to.esri(in.sgrds=c("twi.sgrd","achan.sgrd"), out.grids=c("twi.asc","achan.asc"), prec=1, out.path=getwd())**
grids$achan <- readGDAL("achan.asc")$band1
grids$twi <- readGDAL("twi.asc")$band1
```

Here is my code (the problem is where i put **):

```
library(gstat)
library(spatstat)
library(splancs)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(adehabitat)
library(rgdal)
library(spgrass6)
library(ggExtra)
# environnement pour GRASS
loc <- initGRASS("/usr/lib/grass64", home=tempdir(), override = TRUE)
#-------------------------------
# 1. Data import and preparation
#-------------------------------
# Load the data:

data(bei)
bei.data <- as.data.frame(bei)
bei.elev.data <- as.data.frame(bei.extra$elev)
ggplot(bei.elev.data, aes(x, y, z = value)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + geom_point(aes(x, y, z = NULL), data = bei.data, size = 2, pch = "+") + scale_fill_gradientn(colour = terrain.colors(4)) + opts(title = "Beilschmiedia (Tropical rain forest trees)")
class(bei.extra[[1]])
# Export to a GIS (for visual exploration):
grids <- as(bei.extra[[1]], "SpatialGridDataFrame")
names(grids)[1] <- "elev"
grids$grad <- as(bei.extra[[2]], "SpatialGridDataFrame")$v
writeRAST6(grids["elev"], "dem", zcol = "elev",  ignore.stderr = TRUE)
writeRAST6(grids["grad"], "grad", zcol = "grad", ignore.stderr = TRUE)
bei.pnt <- data.frame(x=bei$x, y=bei$y, no=rep(1, length(bei$x)))
coordinates(bei.pnt) <- ~x+y
# reformat the point pattern so it fits the grids:
bei.ppp <- ppp(coordinates(bei.pnt)[,1], coordinates(bei.pnt)[,2], marks=bei.pnt$no, window=as(grids[1], "owin"))
# Generate the wetness index and vertical distance from the channel network in GRASS and import back to R:
# Work on  GRASS:
execGRASS("g.region", parameters=list(rast="dem"))
execGRASS("g.region", parameters=list(rast="grad"))
execGRASS("r.info", parameters = list(map = "dem"))
execGRASS("r.info", parameters = list(map = "grad"))
gmeta6()
# wetness index
execGRASS("r.topidx", flags = "overwrite", parameters = list(input = "dem", output = "twi"))

# r.stream.extract
execGRASS("g.list", parameters =  list(type = "rast"))
execGRASS("r.stream.extract", flags =  "overwrite", parameters = list(elevation = "dem", stream_rast = "stream", direction = "stream_dir", threshold = as.integer(10)))
#execGRASS("r.watershed", flags = c("m", "overwrite"), parameters = list(elevation = "dem", stream = "stream", threshold = as.integer(10)))
# altitude above channel
**execGRASS("r.stream.distance", flags = "overwrite", parameters = list(stream = "stream", dir = "stream_dir",  dem = "dem", method = "downstream", elevation = "achan"))**
# spline to fill 
execGRASS("r.fillnulls", flags = "overwrite" ,parameters = list(input = "achan", output = "achan"))
# exportation
grids$achan <- readRAST6("achan")@data$achan
grids$twi <- readRAST6("twi")@data$twi
```

So my question is what is really **Saga altitude above channel** (if possible in plain English) and how to compute this using GRASS ?
I'm made several researches (for weeks now), and may be it's right place here.

Comment: Hmm, from my half-minute of research, it looks like Altitude above channel as a function name is pretty specific to Saga GIS.  I do not know what it is called in other software packages.

Comment: For a (vague) definition and a sketch of Saga's algorithm see http://books.google.com/books?id=iZXBeNOzOPEC&pg=PA217&lpg=PA217&dq=Saga+altitude+above+channel&source=bl&ots=TM1MKJD73u&sig=fPz-fZobQoqpjLRV9jpuTtePFiQ&hl=en&ei=0H96Tb7OMfO10QHS7ZjsAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Saga%20altitude%20above%20channel&f=false

Comment: @whuber: Thank's for the link, i hope that it's still possible to do this using GRASS. I'll try to understand the algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm that SAGA uses is explained in this paper(p17): http://downloads.sourceforge.net/saga-gis/hbpl19_02.pdf

Comment: Very good article to understand without math the algorithm used...i'll try to check the C++ code later to understand the math and the implementation...nevertheless i'm new to grass, so it will take time for me to port code this into grass

Comment: I have no experience with saga, but somebody wrote about calling saga from grass. May be more interesting than recoding the algorithm.
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/Executing%20SAGA%20Modules%20with%20the%20Python%20Interface
Apart from that, we (saga, grass, sextante) should really cooperate more on these algorithms and their documentation.

Comment: i agree with you about compatibility with those algorithms, and i would also like to thank you for the sagacvs repository for ubuntu, there was a seg_fault bug in 2.05 and now the 2.06 version runs fine. So i'll use grass as my main gis tool, and saga when it will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted the author of r.stream.distance (and other modules, Jarek Jasiewicz) and he answered (reported here with permission):

"Very complex approach. But I wonder what means really different. The main reason could be that grass uses MFD apporach and generate different channel network and different overland flow distance structure.

[Approach] a) is SAGA, results are based on SFD flow direction but is GRASS based on MFD. In fact SAGA and GRASS nad TAUDEM uses the same algorithm, for elevation above channels and as I tested the results are very similar of course with
overhead on different flow routing algorithms.

Hope it is the reason."

Furthermore he told me:

"BTW GRASS wetness index and stream distance won't be compatible due to different flow routing algorithm. GRASS wetness index is based on SFD flow routing algorithm. But as far as I know SAGA or TAS offer wetness index based on MFD"

Note: MFD based wetness index is planned to be added to GRASS.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information..so i'll stick with that result waiting for new feature in GRASS 7. BTW i know that you are really involved into GRASS development, and just want to thank you, it's really a wonderful piece of software.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)